# Sharing Ofstream pointer and rule of 3

Tags: pointers, copy-constructor, ofstream

I am trying to fix a memory leak found is this code by val-grind. I did not write it, but I reduced the original code down to using ofstream and not filebuf and ostream.

The problem is I can't figure out how to properly delete the ofstream pointer which is shared and called from a virtual getter method in other code. I think this code violates the rule of 3 but trying different assignment and copy constructors did not work.

Below is an example of the basic code I am trying to fix, when it goes to delete the ofstream pointer is seg faults. Before the segfault I was getting a double delete error.

If anyone can please help, I seem to be stuck here, thanks.

```
class myLogger
{
public:

 myLogger(std::string testName);

 void createFileLog();

 ...

protected:

 std::ofstream*  my_LogStream;

};

void MyLogger::createFileLog()
{
    if(Created == false) 
    {
        m_pLogStream = new std::ofstream(logFileName.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
        Created = true; 
    }
}

myLogger::~myLogger()
{
    if(m_pLogStream)
    {
        delete m_pLogStream;
        m_pLogStream = NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in a higher call it was using a copy and calling the destructor twice.